# Rename text in html,php and css files

Tags: php, html, css

What is the best way to rename text in different files?
Need to rename all text who is ex:
static.website.com to static.newwebsite.com

The text in named in css,php and html files who is on one folder.
Im using Putty to see and change files.
The folder is on Ubuntu

Comment: there should be a search and replace feature on your IDE

Comment: that could handle this change for several files at the same time?

Comment: @Slistryko If it's a decent IDE, sure. Pretty much every one I've used has a "find/replace in project" option.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a terminal open on the Ubuntu machine, change to the directory where the files are (since you said they are all in the same directory) then use the following to replace all instances of `static.website.com` with `static.newwebsite.com`

```sh
sed -i'.bak' 's/static.website.com/static.newwebsite.com/g' ./*.{css,html,php}
```

`-i'.bak'` : `-i` means to edit in place and `'.bak'` will create a backup of the original with the extension `.bak`